# Implementing NimSoft in SL

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

Is it possible to implement all functionalities of monitoring(nimsoft) using Softlayer Java API ?
I've found API, SoftLayer_Monitoring_Agent in SL API. It will provide all necessary APIs to develop ?
My java client version is softlayer-api-client-0.2.2.jar

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the java client to use all the services and methods of the Soflayer's API documented here http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/overview. So if you are thinking in use one of the services or method of the Softlayer's API the java client will work for you.